# UIImage orientation in animation

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uiimageorientation

I want to change my `UIImage` orientation.
I've done this one:

```
image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage 
                            scale:1.0 orientation: UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];
```

And it works fine ! But I have next problem:
I want play `UIImageView` animation with CHANGED IMAGES orientation! But it plays WITHOUT changing! I've get orientation and it was changed - but images show like NOT.

Can someone advice ?

Yes, looks like animation IGNORE image orientation.

thanks,

Comment: Can you rephrase a bit? I don't really understand you.
Do you mean that your animation ignores your `imageOrientation`?

Comment: Yes looks like animation ignore orientation.

Comment: I'm not sure about your question, but why don't you add a transform to your UIImageView that mirrors it? Just google it, should be quite straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying a CGAffineTransform on the image view. If you use a -1 for the vertical scale you should get the effect you want.

Comment: I've try add transform - but then rotate gesture works incorrect

Comment: I see. If the rotation is inverted, you can invert the angle in the recognizer when it reports a rotation.

Answer (score 0):

You will run into this issue if you animate on the orientation-corrected image with [UIImage imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:] on iOS 4.x (or prior versions). To work around this, you have to create a new image by rotating the image to the desired orientation. It works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Add set of images in the array and call that array along with the position of the uiimageview and get the output flow's from the array.

http://www.chuckstar.com/blog/technology/iphone-sample-rotating-uiimage-inside-uiimageview/

Hope this may help you!!!

Comment: yeah they need to change the image in sequence